# Android SDK Mac - android-19 - can I safely delete the x86 or armeabi-v7a directories?

Tags: android

I've got 2 directories in my Android-19 SDK directory.

One is `x86` and the other is `armeabi-v7a`. They each take 755MB.

Can I safely delete one of them and still do Android development?

Similarly, in the `add-ons` directory, I have:

```
addon-google_apis_x86-google-19
addon-google_apis-google-18
addon-google_apis-google-19-1
```

Can any of these be deleted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can uninstall those through the SDK Manager.

[image]

Specifically:

- If you do not want to use the x86 emulator system images, uninstall them
- If you do not want to use the ARM emulator system images, uninstall them